# Windows 7 ssh file server

Tags: ssh, windows-7, file-sharing, file-server

I have looked at the other posts, but have not quite found an answer.

I have a question about windows file sharing over SSH. I have copssh installed and it is working for Remote desktop connections. I have port 22 forwarded on my router etc. I connect from a Mac or Putty with this address:

ssh -l copsshusername 3391:localhost:3389 [external ip]

That works fine.

I would like to configure Windows 7 to allow my ssh account that I use to login, access to certain shared folders. I have documents and videos and things that I would like to be able to download externally.

I have done this before on Linux and a long time ago on XP, but I cannot figure out what I am missing on Windows 7.

There is a designated SSH user that copssh uses to run the service and that I use to to login as.

I have googled and googled and have not found a solution that does everything I need that is why I am turning here for ideas.

I hope I am explaining this correctly. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have SSH port forwarding working already, why not set up an FTP server on the Win7 box and just forward port 21 (FTP) instead of 3389, and use an FTP client to connect and manage your files?

You could use the free [FileZilla server](http://filezilla-project.org/) for this, and the fact that you are already tunneling over SSH will mean that your connection will be secured.

Comment: I have FTP all setup, currently using the built in IIS Windows 7 FTP. It works without SSH, but I cannot get any connection when I select port 22 in FileZilla. I think I have all the port forwarding taken care of. I have been doing research and read that I have to turn off LAN network sharing on Windows 7 to get it to work. I lost my Linux server recently and I am not as familiar with Windows 7. Thanks for the response and I hope that was understandable.

Comment: Do I have to use FileZilla? Does the built in Windows 7 FTP not support sftp? Thanks again.

Comment: No, you can use the straight Windows FTP server if you want. Here's the thing -> You don't need to use SFTP because you are using SSH to make the connection. SSH secures the connection already, so using SFTP would be unnecessary. Look at your example. You connect to your Win7 from another PC on localhost:3391, right? So just do the same thing. Just take your example and substitute 3389 for 21. Then open an FTP client on the PC you are using to connect and connect a **standard** FTP connection to localhost:3391.

Comment: thanks.... That was my original idea, and how I have done it before but I cant get it to work. I might be doing it wrong so I will double check everything. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Are you using Passive mode in your FTP client? Try disabling it and see if that helps...

Comment: Ok so that fixed it from Windows to Windows, but now on my Mac, I am having the same problem. Passive mode is disabled and I connect to ssh as follows: ssh -l computerssh -L 2121:localhost:21 192.168.1.20 The IP is static and the SSH connection seems to work just fine. When I open up FileZilla to connect with: localhost, username (set in Win7 IIS config for anon config), correct pass, and 2121 as the port. It keeps throwing hostname didn't match any configured ftp site. I followed all the Win7 guides i could find on google, so I am stuck. Any Ideas? Thanks again.

Comment: That error message sounds like a problem with the FileZilla client, try adding your system in the Site Manager and connecting that way...